# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined nvd3 donut chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have the following code to draw donut chart using nvd3, I'm getting the above error when I pass dynamic objcect array to datanum. If I hard code the same object array format it is working (drawing donut chart).

code:

contoller:

```
 $scope.getMentions = function ( ) { 
var promise = widgetServices.getMentions( );
 promise.then(function (response) { 
$rootScope.mentionsData = response.data.facet_counts.facet_pivot.toyota_series; console.log($rootScope.mentionsData); // This is $rootScope data im passing to nvd3. 
}, function (errorPayload) { $log.error('failure loading the details', errorPayload); }); } 

//Donut chart example
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.value })
        .y(function(d) { return d.count })
        .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
        //.labelThreshold(.01)  //Configure the minimum slice size for labels to show up
        .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
        .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
        .donutRatio(0.35)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
    ;
    //chart.height(2000); 

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum($rootScope.mentionsData)  //Dynamic data passing from controller
        .transition().duration(350)
        .call(chart);

    return chart;
});
```

Hard coded array: dummy data (chart is drawing with this data)

```
exampleData =
       [
         { 

             "label": "Camry",
             "value" : 248119

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Prius",
             "value" : 246203

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Corolla",
             "value" : 97891

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Tacoma",
             "value" : 57181

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Mirai",
             "value" : 53723

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Highlander",
             "value" : 45351

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "Tundra",
             "value" : 43394

         } , 
         { 

             "label": "4Runner",
             "value" : 38147

         },
         { 

             "label": "RAV4",
             "value" : 34563

         },
         { 

             "label": "Matrix",
             "value" : 31071

         },
         { 

             "label": "Avalon",
             "value" : 22596

         }
       ];
```

Comment: `$rootScope.mentionsData` is `undefined`. Check your spelling and verify that the value is being set.

Comment: I think there is no issue with spelling.  $scope.getMentions = function ( ) {
    
     var promise = widgetServices.getMentions( );//Default dates should be passed
     promise.then(function (response) {
      $rootScope.mentionsData = response.data.facet_counts.facet_pivot.toyota_series;
         console.log($rootScope.mentionsData); // This is $rootScope data im passing to nvd3.
     }, function (errorPayload) {
         $log.error('failure loading the details', errorPayload);
     });
 }

Comment: Promises work asynchronously so it might not be assigned yet when you try to access it. Also, you should edit your question to include that code instead of making it a comment.